# An Inequality Related to Jensen's Inequality and potentially Entropy

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis

What known results in the literature are related to following observation:

---

Let $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a convex and differentiable function.

Let $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a\geq b$. Define the function $g\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ as $g(x) = f(a+x)+f(b-x)$. Then the derivative of $g$ is $g^\prime(x) = f^\prime(a+x) - f^\prime(b-x)$. As $f$ is convex, its derivative $f^\prime$ is nondecreasing. Thus, $g^\prime(x)\geq0$ for $x\geq0$. This shows the following Lemma.

**Lemma 1.** If $a,b,\tilde a,\tilde b\in\mathbb R$ with $a+b = \tilde a + \tilde b$ and $|\tilde a - \tilde b|\leq |a-b|$, then $f(\tilde a) + f(\tilde b) \leq f(a) + f(b)$.

In the "extreme" case, we have $\tilde a=\tilde b=(a + b)/2$ and the Lemma just says $f((a + b)/2) \leq f(a)/2 + f(b)/2$, i.e., $f$ is convex.

We can iterate this idea for $n$ values instead of $2$:

**Theorem 1.** Let $n\in\mathbb N$. Let $a_1, \dots, a_n, \tilde a_1\dots,\tilde a_n\in\mathbb R$. Assume $a_1 \leq \dots \leq a_n$ and $\tilde a_1 \leq \dots \leq \tilde a_n$. Assume
$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \tilde a_i$. Moreover, assume that we can "generate" $(\tilde a_i)_i$ from $(a_i)_i$ with the following process.
Let $m\in\mathbb N$. Set $a_{i,0} = a_i$ and $a_{i,m} = \tilde a_i$. To create $(a_{i,k+1})_i$ from $(a_{i,k})_i$, Select $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ with $i<j$ and redistribute value from $a_{j,k}$ to $a_{i,k}$, i.e., choose $x \in [0, (a_{j,k}-a_{i,k})/2]$ and set $a_{i,k+1} = a_{i,k} + x$ and $a_{j,k+1} = a_{j,k} - x$. Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(\tilde a_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n f(a_i)\,.$$

With the iterative construction of $(\tilde a_i)_i$, we can apply Lemma 1 in every step to prove Theorem 1.

In the "extreme" case, we have $\tilde a_1 = \dots = \tilde a_n = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ and we obtain $$f\left(\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right) \leq \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n f(a_i)\,,$$
i.e., Jensen's inequality.

---

I assume that this is a known phenomenon - maybe a corollary of a more fundamental inequality. It seems related to some notion of entropy in the sense that one changes a distribution of values in the direction of becoming more uniform, i.e., entropy increases. The theorem I am looking for potentially says something like: if $(\tilde a_i)_i$ has higher entropy than $(a_i)_i$ then $\sum_{i=1}^n f(\tilde a_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n f(a_i)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is [Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality), applied to
$$
 x_k = a_{n+1-k} \, , \, y_k = \tilde a_{n+1-k} \, ,
$$
i.e. the original sequence and the final sequence, in decreasing order.

Every step in the construction decreases $y_1 + \cdots + y_k$ or does not change it, while preserving the total sum.

So $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ [majorizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) $(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$, and therefore
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^n f(y_k) \le \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k) \, .
$$

It suffices that $f$ is convex, it is not needed that the function is differentiable everywhere.